# Why are all my possible conversation answers in red?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When i'm given the opportunity to choose a dialog, they all appear in red but when i choose the "nicer" of the 2 i get paragon points awarded. I only see red options, not blue or grey.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: do you have any paragon points?

Answer (score 9):

The UI in Mass Effect 3 has a silly flaw -- the color of selected dialog is always red. You're not using renegade options, you're just using normal conversation.

Handy Rule of Thumb: 
[image]

Not every conversation has Charm / Intimidate options - these will only show up if they're available.

Comment: Also, sometimes the 'Reputation Neutral Response' is really just 'Less Renegade' or 'Less Paragon'.